Running selenium python on Windows docker selenium throws exception : Session not created exception - chrome falied to start
I'm new to Docker, and this is my first time using containers to run my Selenium (version 4.24.0) tests. I'm encountering issues when trying to run Selenium (Python/pytest) within a Windows Docker container.
The error I'm receiving is:
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
(chrome not reachable)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Chrome\chrome-win64\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Im running with following options:
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_path = r"C:\Program Files\Chrome\chrome-win64\chrome.exe"
chrome_options.binary_location = chrome_path
service = ChromeService(r"C:\Program Files\Chrome\ChromeDriver\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)


I'm using the following Docker base image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
Here is the content of my Dockerfile:
Use Windows Server Core as the base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
Set the shell to PowerShell for the following RUN commands
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]
Install Python 3.12.4
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.4/python-3.12.4-amd64.exe -OutFile python-installer.exe
RUN Start-Process -FilePath python-installer.exe -Args '/silent /install TargetDir=C:\Python' -NoNewWindow -Wait
RUN Remove-Item -Force python-installer.exe
RUN [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH + ';C:\Python', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
Install Chrome
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/129.0.6668.58/win64/chrome-win64.zip -OutFile chrome_win64.zip
RUN Expand-Archive -Path chrome_win64.zip -DestinationPath 'C:\Program Files\Chrome' -Force
RUN Remove-Item -Force chrome_win64.zip
Install ChromeDriver (compatible with Chrome version 129.0.6668.58)
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/129.0.6668.58/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip -OutFile chromedriver_win64.zip
RUN Expand-Archive -Path chromedriver_win64.zip -DestinationPath 'C:\Program Files\Chrome\ChromeDriver' -Force
RUN if (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files\Chrome\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe') { Write-Host "ChromeDriver installed" } else { Write-Host "ChromeDriver not installed" }
RUN Remove-Item -Force chromedriver_win64.zip
Set environment variables for browser drivers (assuming the drivers will be in the container's project folder)
ENV CHROMEWEBDRIVER="C:\Program Files\Chrome\ChromeDriver\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe"
ENV PATH="C:\Python;C:\Python\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Chrome\chrome-win64;C:\Program Files\Chrome\ChromeDriver\chromedriver-win64"
Set the working directory to /app where your code will be mounted or copied
WORKDIR /app
Copy the project files, including requirements.txt, into the container
COPY . .
Install Python dependencies from requirements.txt
RUN ["C:\Python\python.exe", "-m", "pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]


I’ve tried several versions of Chrome, but I matched the ChromeDriver and Chrome to version 129.0.6668.58, which works perfectly on my local IDE.

I've also attempted to place the ChromeDriver in my working directory and tried specifying absolute paths for both the driver and Chrome executable, but nothing worked.

I expect my tests to run successfully through the pytest framework I built within the Windows Docker container, as they do in my IDE. Any help would be appreciated!

    

